# How to solve truncated images created by php script?

Tags: php, image, mirror

I have an image that is severed by a php script. I call it as such.

```
 <img src="/index.php/image-name.jpg">
```

If the image is more than 5 minutes old my script will retrieve a new copy of the image from a data provider and then display the new image.

When the website that provides the images has a load and this script goes to fetch a new copy, it will often only display the top part of the image. Firebug will tell me that the image is corrupt or truncated. If I open the image in a new tab, my sever has a full copy. If I run the script a second time within 5 minutes it works perfectly.

It is looking like if it takes more than a certain amount of time to get the image it fails and only shows the top part. Any thoughts on how to make it wait longer before giving up? Or maybe I am completely on the wrong track with what is going wrong.

```
<?php
  // get the image name from the uri
  $path= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $image = explode("/", $path);
  $image=$image[3];//Get the file name
  $image=str_replace('%20',' ', $image); //make it all spaces

  $localimage='./road_images/'.$image; //where to find the image on the sever
  // check if the image exists, this prevents some kinds of attacks
  if (is_file($localimage)) {
    $age = filemtime($localimage);     // get the file age
    if ($age < time() - (60*5)) { // 5 mins old
        $simage='http://www.someplace/cams/'.$image;
        $simage=str_replace(' ', '%20', $simage);//need to remove the spaces for URLs
        copy($simage, $localimage);
    }
    // serve the image to the user.
    $fp = fopen($localimage, 'r');
    // send the right headers
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($localimage));
    // dump the picture and stop the script
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit();
  }
  else
  {
        echo("Error, no such file: '$image'");
  }
?>
```

EDIT: Have discovered that by editing out

```
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($localimage));
```

It works as expected. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: I am mirroring another website that will not let me hotlink. The image updates every 5 minutes. If my copy of the image is more than 5 minutes old I go get a new copy and display it. If it is less than 5 minutes old, then I use the copy I already have.

Comment: ohh.. do you know the file sizes? Can be file is too big for your web server. (ignore my last comment)

Comment: The images are pretty small.  A big one would be 328 × 314 pixels and 30KB. At night most of the images are black or close to it and closer to 10KB.

Answer (score 0):

That was painful. I was passing the wrong Content-Length header value. Editing out the content length solved it so that it worked just fine. Considering it is static content, I do not know why what I have above does not work.

With more research figured out a way that works.

I put `ob_start()` near the start.
The new Content-Length header `header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());`goes at the bottom, just before script exits.

Done that way it works every time and is nice to the browser.